# $this->db->last_query() not picking up the right query

Tags: sql

I've got a Active Record query which i need to grab the sql from, so i'm doing the query and then i'm doing for example

```
$query = $this->EE->db->select('foo')->get('bar');     
$bob = $this->EE->db->last_query();
```

Now, on my local machine it picks it up fine. But, on the live site it's picking up a query of the exp_sites table and basically just returns the contents of the exp_sites table for this site (it's not msm so there is only one row). That's not the query i want, so how is it getting picked up there?!?!

Anyone know why this might be? Caching? A full moon?

Comment: Is DB caching enabled on the live site?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it. I'm sure i've seen this before but cannot remember the fix. Gaaah!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put this above your query.

```
$this->EE->db->save_queries = TRUE;
```

`EE_Config.php` sets the `save_queries` value dynamically based on debug/profiler settings, ignoring settings in `database.php`. This is why it worked fine in your local environment.

Answer (score 4):

This will do it:

```
$this->EE->db->save_queries = TRUE;
$query = $this->EE->db->select('foo')->get('bar');
$bob = end($this->EE->db->queries);
$this->EE->db->save_queries = FALSE;
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, last_query() just doesn't work in EE... it never has (or at least when I've tried to use it)

easiest way to do it (which is what I do) is

```
$query = $this->EE->db->select('foo')->get('bar');
$bob = $query->result_array();
```

Someone infinitely more intelligent than I will probably be able to tell you why it doesn't work, but suffice to say - I gave up trying to figure it out.

Comment: I want the compiled sql though, not the result_array() in this scenario. Thanks though!!

Comment: Ahhh OK - So in that case try doing $this->EE->db->cache_off() before your $query and see what happens?